# Qt - QSql Unable to fetch row, no query on attempt to insert

Tags: qt, insert, sqlite, qtsql

I'm trying to insert data into a table. Here's the code:

```
void AddContacts::saveContact() {

    QString first_name = ui->lineFirstName->text();
    QString last_name = ui->lineLastName->text();
    QString street_address = ui->lineStreetAddress->text();
    QString city = ui->lineCity->text();
    QString state = ui->comboBoxState->currentText();
    QString zip_code = ui->lineZip->text();
    QString personal_email = ui->linePersonalEmail->text();
    QString work_email = ui->lineWorkEmail->text();
    QString home_phone = ui->lineHomePhone->text();
    QString cellular_phone = ui->lineCellularPhone->text();
    QString work_phone = ui->lineWorkPhone->text();
    QString pager = ui->linePager->text();
    QString facebook = ui->lineFacebook->text();
    QString twitter = ui->lineTwitter->text();
    QString notes = ui->textEditNotes->toPlainText();

    // Insert into the database
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("db.db3");
    db.open();

    QSqlQuery qry;
    QString query = "INSERT INTO (id, first_name, last_name, street_address, city, state, zip_code, personal_email, work_email, home_phone, cellular_phone, work_phone, pager, facebook, twitter, notes) VALUES('null','" + first_name + "','" + last_name +"','" + street_address + "','" + city + "','" + state + "','" + zip_code + "','" + personal_email + "','" + work_email + "','" + home_phone + "','" + cellular_phone + "','" + work_phone + "','" + pager + "','" + facebook + "','" + twitter + "', '" + notes + "')";
    qry.prepare(query);

    if(!qry.exec()) {
        qDebug() << qry.lastError();
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Success!";
    }
```

Here is what I used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
id int primary key,
first_name varchar(20),
last_name varchar(20),
street_address text,
city varchar(30),
state varchar(20),
zip_code varchar(10),
personal_email varchar(40),
work_email varchar(40),
home_phone varchar(12),
cellular_phone varchar(12),
work_phone varchar(12),
pager varchar(12),
facebook text,
twitter varchar(20),
notes text);
```

I'm getting this error:

> QSqlError(-1, "Unable to fetch row", "No query")

I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong. Can you find anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't insert a string `'null'` as a value for column `id`. Use a valid integer instead. If you really want the first row to have a `NULL` id, the SQL statement looks like this `... VALUES (NULL, ...`.

Your code is very prone to errors since you don't escape apostrophes in your input. If some of your text fields contain a `'`, your SQL statement will fail. You should bind your columns to variables. This is from the Qt references and you should use this approach:

```
 QSqlQuery query;
 query.prepare("INSERT INTO contacts (id, first_name, last_name) "
               "VALUES (:id, :first_name, :last_name)");
 query.bindValue(":id", 1001);
 query.bindValue(":first_name", first_name);
 query.bindValue(":last_name", last_name);
 query.exec();
```

Answer (score 3):

hi friend i think you miss your table name in query.

```
QString query = "INSERT INTO ??? (id, first_name, last_name, street_address, city, state, zip_code, personal_email, work_email, home_phone, cellular_phone, work_phone, pager, facebook, twitter, notes) VALUES('null','" + first_name + "','" + last_name +"','" + street_address + "','" + city + "','" + state + "','" + zip_code + "','" + personal_email + "','" + work_email + "','" + home_phone + "','" + cellular_phone + "','" + work_phone + "','" + pager + "','" + facebook + "','" + twitter + "', '" + notes + "')";
qry.prepare(query);
```

i put question mark in that place